# How to set input field to show buttons once word is typed in angular2

Tags: html, angular

I have an input field, and i want that input field to give add and change button based on media present in it or not.
HTML:

```
<div class = "type-video"  [hidden]= "selectedImage !='video'" >
      <span style="margin-left: 12%;">or </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" (change)="editPinImage($event,media)" style="width: 28%;margin-right: 24%;">
      </div>
```

Here i get an input with all fields but i am unable to add anything. If i type for one, it is getting input to all fields

Comment: What's the code behind editPinImage() looking like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I understand that you are triyng to differentiate between `new` and `edit` forms.

Since you are talking about media, you can use `media.id` or whatever your field is in `*ngIf` condition

```
<div class = "type-video"  [hidden]= "selectedImage !='video'" *ngIf="!media.id">
    <span style="margin-left: 12%;">Add</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" (change)="editPinImage($event,media)" style="width: 28%;margin-right: 24%;">
</div>

<div class = "type-video"  [hidden]= "selectedImage !='video'" *ngIf="media.id">
    <span style="margin-left: 12%;">Change</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" (change)="editPinImage($event,media)" style="width: 28%;margin-right: 24%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this was what i was searching for